# How to create decils in SAS inside a grouped variable

Tags: sas

I want create decils in each level of a grouped variable in SAS.

For example, if I had the students' marks by subject, I would like to create calculate decils for each subject. Filtering the database for each subject, calculating the deciles and then merging them is not a solution since the problem I am dealing with has more than 80 levels in the grouped variable.

Comment: Please include whatever you've tried in your questions so we can understand what approaches you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proc rank with a BY variable.

```
proc rank data=have out=want ranks=10;
by subject;
var marks;
ranks mark_rank;
run;
```